# Joining 2 tables with part of a Composite Primary key in JPA, Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, join, spring-data-jpa

I have an old database where can't change the schema so I have to adapt my code to work.

Within that db I have two tables which I'd like to join.
The main Table called SFTSEB2 has a 5 Column Composite primary key: empfkey, ebmsg, ebbord, ebsort, ebrefn only these will going to fulfill the uniqueness on that Table.

I'd like to join SFTSEB3 to SFTSEB2 but based on only 4 Columns: empfkey, ebmsg, ebbord, ebsort

Entites:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SFTSEB2")
@IdClass(Sftseb2ID.class)
@Immutable
public class Sftseb2 {
    @Id
    private String empfkey;
    
    @Id
    private String ebmsg;
    
    @Id
    private String ebbord;
    
    @Id
    private int ebsort;

    private int ebbpos;

    private String ebsdgn;
    
    @Id
    private String ebrefn;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "empfkey", referencedColumnName = "empfkey", insertable = false, updatable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "ebmsg", referencedColumnName = "ebmsg", insertable = false, updatable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "ebbord", referencedColumnName = "ebbord", insertable = false, updatable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "ebsort", referencedColumnName = "ebsort", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    })
    List<Sftseb3> sftseb3;
    
    //GettersSetters
    ...
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SFTSEB3")
@IdClass(Sftseb3ID.class)
@Immutable
public class Sftseb3 {
    @Id
    private String empfkey;
    
    @Id
    private String ebmsg;
    
    @Id
    private String ebbord;
    
    @Id
    private int ebsort;
    
    @Id
    private int ebsrt2;
    
    @Id
    private String ebsdgn;
   
    private int ebbpos;
    
    private String ebstst;
    
    private String ebstsc;
    
    
    //GettersSetters
    //...
}
```

Unfortunately I can get past this because hibernate is giving back:

`A Foreign key refering Sftseb2 from Sftseb3 has the wrong number of column. should be 5`

I tried to have a bi-directional mapping so the complete JoinColumns part went to Sftseb3 with a @ManyToOne and Sftseb2 would only contain the mappedBy at the @OneToMany but I got the same issue.
As I see there is no way to have different PK on an entity and Join another table to it based on part of the PK or even other columns? Why?

If I reduce the number of @Id columns to match in the two tables so Sftseb2's @Ids: empfkey, ebmsg, ebbord, ebsort then it starts to work, however because this is non-unique all instances of Sftseb2 will be the same...

Comment: Have you tryed with a jpql query?  You can get rid of the mapping in the entities. You can also check with a criteria query making a cross join. In the worst scenario you can try with a native query

Comment: Is this really a OneToMany? In theory, it should have a clear FK that references a single row; but as the error states, the 4 columns you've shown are only 4 of the 5 you've marked as composites to uniquely identify Sftseb2, so it isn't complete. So it really is more of a ManyToMany. This mapping isn't good for JPA as it has no idea who controls that fk; what should happen if you try to change the reference, how can it save such a change? So what is the point of requiring this list in your model?

Comment: My goal would be to fetch every related rows from various tables and send them as an xml structure for further processing.

So:
For-each row in SFTSEB2 fetch rows from SFTSEB3 where the empfkey, ebmsg, ebbord, ebsort equals what the actual row from SFTSEB2 has.

This should behave like a OneToMany because for each row of STFSEB2 there can be OneOrMore SFTSEB3. Although based on the limited set of columns I agree that this can't be unique so from that point of view this is more of a ManyToMany.... 

Isn't it solvable with Entity joins?

Comment: I more mean the purpose of your model. Joins are easy to do without requiring actual references in your object model. JPQL "Select s3 from Sftseb2 s2 join Sftseb3 s3  on ( s2.empfkey = s3.empfkey AND s2.ebmsg = s3.ebmsg AND s2.ebbord = s3.ebbord AND s2.ebsort = s3.ebsort) where ..." If your provider doesn't support the join on clause, you can add it to the where clause yourself. If you want the list fetched each time you fetch Sftseb2 instances, you'll have to resort to non-JPA mappings as JPA requires fks reference primary keys to allow for entity identity, lookups and caching.